# Find files inside sub-directories with different names (to remove them with mtime)

Tags: find, rm

I have a set of client folders on a server. Each client has backups inside a "backup" directory like so;

`~/backups/<CLIENT_NAME>/{daily, weekly, monthly}/{databases, directories, logs}`

I'd like to find a way to search every client folder and remove files older than a specific time.
Can I do this without doing a `find` for each client? So far I have to do 3 `find` for each client, and there's dozens.

```
find ~/backups/<CLIENT_NAME>/daily/{directories,databases,logs} -mtime +6 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find ~/backups/<CLIENT_NAME>/weekly/{directories,databases,logs} -mtime +27 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find ~/backups/<CLIENT_NAME>/monthly/{directories,databases,logs} -mtime +31 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: You could replace `<CLIENT_NAME>` by `{client1,client2,...clientN}`, but then you'd risk overflowing the command line buffer.  Just do a loop for clients.  With a few dozens of clients the difference in efficiency would be too small to measure.  Start worrying about that when you have >100k directories.

Comment: unfortunately I need to keep the CLIENT_NAME as they are, but thank you

Comment: Without giving away too much info, why do you need to keep the name the way it is?

Comment: Because they come from an rsync that creates the CLIENT_NAME based on the source server $HOSTNAME. That and the boss says so :-)